# Why is the event MqttMsgPublishReceived never triggered?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mqtt

I'm not unfamiliar with MQTT and C# but I want to make a console application for dotnetcore using the M2MqttDotnetCore library.

I've tried the code below (not very familiar with console applications). The sender seems to work fine, if I use another MQTT client that subscribes to the topic I can see the data arriving just fine.

The receiver however never gets it event Client_MqttMsgPublishReceived triggered and I don't know why...

**Sender:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;

namespace SensorMeasurementToMQTT
{
    class Program
    {

        MqttClient client;
        Random random;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();
            program.Run();
        }


        public void Run()
        {
            random = new Random();

            while(true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (client == null)

                    {
                        client = new MqttClient("test.mosquitto.org"); //Of je kan hier ook jouw eigen broker gebruiken uit vorig labo.
                        client.Connect(new Guid().ToString(), null, null, true, 10);

                        SensorMeasurement sensorMeasurement = new SensorMeasurement();
                        sensorMeasurement.IDSensor = 1;
                        sensorMeasurement.Datetime = new DateTime(2020, 5, 17, 14, 53, 0);
                        sensorMeasurement.Value = Math.Round(18 + random.NextDouble() * 5, 2); 

                        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sensorMeasurement);

                        client.Publish("mytopic/test", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE, false);

                        Thread.Sleep(1000);

                        client.Disconnect();
                        client = null;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to upload data to MQTT");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    class SensorMeasurement
    {
        public int IDSensor { get; set; }
        public DateTime Datetime { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
    }


}
```

**Receiver:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Text;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;

namespace MQTTToDatabase
{
    class Program
    {

        MqttClient client;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();
            program.ConnectAndSubscribe();

            Console.ReadLine();

            program.DisconnectAndUnsubscribe();
        }


        public void ConnectAndSubscribe()
        {
            try
            {
                if (client == null)
                {
                    client = new MqttClient("test.mosquitto.org");
                    client.Connect(new Guid().ToString(), null, null, true, 10);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    if (client.IsConnected)
                    {
                        client.Subscribe(new string[] { "mytopic/test" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE });
                        client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += Client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        public void DisconnectAndUnsubscribe()
        {
            try
            {
                if (client.IsConnected) client.Disconnect();
                client.MqttMsgPublishReceived -= Client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
                client = null;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        private void Client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
        {
            SensorMeasurement sensorMeasurement = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SensorMeasurement>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message));
        }
    }

    class SensorMeasurement
    {
        public int IDSensor { get; set; }
        public DateTime Datetime { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Comment: Update: the two of them work separately but never together. The sender can publish to a topic and using a third party MQTT client (a javascript website) I can see the message.

The receiver can see the messages published from a third party MQTT client (the same javascript website). I really can't see what I'm missing here. Are you not allowed to connect to the same broker from the same IP?

Answer (score 2):

I got it working and I changed two things:

1/ The order of connection / event subscription.

```
client = new MqttClient("test.mosquitto.org");
client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += Client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
client.Connect("Receiver");

if (client.IsConnected)
{
    client.Subscribe(new string[] { "mytopic/test" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
}
```

And I did something similar for the sender. First event subscription, then connection.

2/ The connect method now uses only a simple text string, no GUID, no overloading.